# Accessing a timeout variable of another function inside a function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

In javascript, I am doing something like this

```
first_function: function() {
              var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
              // doing something 
              }, 300000);
           },
```

In another function, after doing something important I have to access the `timeout` variable and clear timeout.

```
 second_function : function () {
           // after opening the hardware, have to cleartimeout from first_function
            hardware.open().then(function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
           // calling first_function only after hardware open
            this.first_function();
```

But, I get undefined variable `timeout` , how can I solve this problem?

I cannot call `this.first_function()` before resolving the promise from `then()`

Comment: move the variable into the same scope as the functions 'first_function' and 'second_function'

Comment: just create the `var timeout` out of the function, as a global variable. `var timeout;`

Comment: @CalvinNunes cannot do that, I cannot create a variable out of the function

Comment: global namespace polution should be avoided. The functions seem to be part of an object so I think it would be best to turn the timeout variable into an attribute of that object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just store `timeout` variable as another property, e.g. `this.timeout`:

```
first_function: function() {
  this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // doing something 
  }, 300000);
},


second_function: function() {
  // after opening the hardware, have to cleartimeout from first_function
  hardware.open().then(() => {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);

    // calling first_function only after hardware open
    this.first_function();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put `timeout` in another property like this or outside of your functions.

```
var timeout;

first_function: function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // doing something 
  }, 300000);
},

second_function: function() {
  // after opening the hardware, have to cleartimeout from first_function
  hardware.open().then(() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    // calling first_function only after hardware open
    this.first_function();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows;

```
var first_function  = _ => setTimeout(_ => doSomething, 300000),
    second_function = cto => hardware.open()
                                     .then(_ => clearTimeout(cto));

second_function(first_function());
```